# Filling the NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm querying the last 10 days worth of data for a particular object:

```
AMT     READING_TIME            DATE
-----------------------------------------------------
                                12-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
                                11-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
                                10-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24545   09-MAR-15 10:54:00 AM   09-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24549   08-MAR-15 09:51:00 PM   08-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24549   07-MAR-15 11:37:00 PM   07-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24549   06-MAR-15 10:08:00 PM   06-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24556   05-MAR-15 11:35:00 PM   05-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
7605    04-MAR-15 07:36:00 PM   04-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
9631    03-MAR-15 02:20:00 PM   03-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
```

The READING_TIME is the date that corresponds to the AMT. That is actual data in our system. The DATE is simply the last ten days, today being at the top. For the last 3 days, I haven't got a corresponding record, so the AMT column is NULL. Keep in mind, this could happen in the middle of the set of data, anywhere actually.

If the AMT is NULL, I want it to use the AMT of the MAX(READING_TIME) that is less than the record's DATE value. Here's what I've been using so far:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT AMOUNT
  FROM HISTORY
  WHERE ID   = A.ID
  AND (CODE IS NOT NULL AND CODE  <> -1)
  AND TO_DATE(NVL(READING_DATE, TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
    || ' '
    || NVL(READING_TIME, TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'HH24MI')), 'YYYYMMDD HH24MI') = A.READING_TIME
  ) AS AMOUNT,
  A.READING_TIME,
  A."DATE"
FROM
  (SELECT 329 AS ID,
    (SELECT MAX(TO_DATE(NVL(READING_DATE, TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
      || ' '
      || NVL(READING_TIME, TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'HH24MI')), 'YYYYMMDD HH24MI')) AS READING_DATE
    FROM HISTORY TH
    WHERE TH.ID   = 329
    AND (TH.CODE IS NOT NULL AND TH.CODE  <> -1)
    AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(NVL(TH.READING_DATE, TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
        || ' ' || NVL(TH.READING_TIME, TO_CHAR(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'HH24MI')), 'YYYYMMDD HH24MI')) = DATES."DATE"
    ) AS READING_TIME,
    DATES."DATE"
  FROM
    (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 - LEVEL AS "DATE"
     FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
    ) DATES
  ) A
```

FYI, these dates in the system come as strings to start, thus the conversion. There is also the fun caveat that some are NULL, so we use TRANSACTION_DATE if that is the case. The HISTORY table has multiple records per day. We are grabbing latest record for a particular day.

My final data set should look like this:

```
AMT     READING_TIME            DATE
-----------------------------------------------------
24545   09-MAR-15 10:54:00 AM   12-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24545   09-MAR-15 10:54:00 AM   11-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24545   09-MAR-15 10:54:00 AM   10-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24545   09-MAR-15 10:54:00 AM   09-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24549   08-MAR-15 09:51:00 PM   08-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24549   07-MAR-15 11:37:00 PM   07-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24549   06-MAR-15 10:08:00 PM   06-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
24556   05-MAR-15 11:35:00 PM   05-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
7605    04-MAR-15 07:36:00 PM   04-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
9631    03-MAR-15 02:20:00 PM   03-MAR-15 12:00:00 AM
```

UPDATE: Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1492f/1) of the scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions066.htm#SQLRF00642) to do this. But first, I think your original query
can be simplified.

```
with dates(date_) as (
    select trunc(sysdate) + 1 - level
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10
    )
select 
    h.id,
    d.date_,
    max(amount) keep (dense_rank first order by coalesce(to_date(h.reading_date || h.reading_time,'yyyymmddhh24mi'), h.transaction_date) desc) amt,
    max(coalesce(to_date(h.reading_date || h.reading_time,'yyyymmddhh24mi'), h.transaction_date)) reading_time
from dates      d
left outer join history h
    on d.date_ = coalesce(to_date(h.reading_date,'yyyymmdd'),trunc(h.transaction_date))
    and h.id = 329
    and h.code <> -1 and h.code is not null
group by h.id, d.date_;
```

Instead of scanning the table twice, you can do it in a single scan.

1. Derived column reading_time can be simplified assuming reading_date/reading_time will be null or not null at the same time.
2. [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) function is used to get the amount corresponding to the max reading time.

Once you have this, apply the FIRST_VALUE function.

```
with dates(date_) as (
    select trunc(sysdate) + 1 - level
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10
    )
select 
    first_value(amt) ignore nulls over (order by date_ desc rows between current row and unbounded following) amt,
    first_value(reading_time) ignore nulls over (order by date_ desc rows between current row and unbounded following) reading_time,
    date_
from (
    select 
        h.id,
        d.date_,
        max(amount) keep (dense_rank first order by coalesce(to_date(h.reading_date || h.reading_time,'yyyymmddhh24mi'), h.transaction_date) desc) amt,
        max(coalesce(to_date(h.reading_date || h.reading_time,'yyyymmddhh24mi'), h.transaction_date)) reading_time
    from dates      d
    left outer join history h
        on d.date_ = coalesce(to_date(h.reading_date,'yyyymmdd'),trunc(h.transaction_date))
        and h.id = 329
        and h.code <> -1 and h.code is not null
    group by h.id, d.date_
    )
order by date_ desc;
```

Example:

```
SQL> select * from myt order by date_ desc;

       AMT READING_TIME               DATE_
---------- -------------------------- --------------------------
                                      12-MAR-2015 00:00:00
                                      11-MAR-2015 00:00:00
                                      10-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24545 09-MAR-2015 10:54:00       09-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24549 08-MAR-2015 21:51:00       08-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24549 07-MAR-2015 23:37:00       07-MAR-2015 00:00:00
                                      06-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24556 05-MAR-2015 23:35:00       05-MAR-2015 00:00:00
      7605 04-MAR-2015 19:36:00       04-MAR-2015 00:00:00
      9631 03-MAR-2015 14:20:00       03-MAR-2015 00:00:00

10 rows selected.

SQL> select 
first_value(amt) ignore nulls over (order by date_ desc rows between current row and unbounded following) amt,
first_value(reading_time) ignore nulls over (order by date_ desc rows between current row and unbounded following) reading_time,
date_
from myt order by date_ desc;
  2    3    4    5  
       AMT READING_TIME               DATE_
---------- -------------------------- --------------------------
     24545 09-MAR-2015 10:54:00       12-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24545 09-MAR-2015 10:54:00       11-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24545 09-MAR-2015 10:54:00       10-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24545 09-MAR-2015 10:54:00       09-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24549 08-MAR-2015 21:51:00       08-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24549 07-MAR-2015 23:37:00       07-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24556 05-MAR-2015 23:35:00       06-MAR-2015 00:00:00
     24556 05-MAR-2015 23:35:00       05-MAR-2015 00:00:00
      7605 04-MAR-2015 19:36:00       04-MAR-2015 00:00:00
      9631 03-MAR-2015 14:20:00       03-MAR-2015 00:00:00

10 rows selected.
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1492f/24)

Comment: Not rendering any results on the initial query. I believe it is due to the D.DATE_ = TO_DATE(H.READING_DATE || H.READING_TIME) line in the ON clause. I return no records.

Comment: Current day back to March 9 do not show up though. They aren't within the query. They would need to show up and take the first value that isn't null.

Comment: Its the where clause that is filtering the records. If you change it to ON clause, it should be fine.

Comment: I took out the WHERE within the sqlfiddle, tacked on the AND instead to make it a part of the ON clause. I don't see any of the days after the 9th.

Comment: And it works... awesome. Thanks. Much quicker explain plan than my attempts